# Calculate intraclass correlation by group in R

Tags: r, correlation

I need some programming/statistic help.
I have a database with multiple groups (variable "group"). The members of each group rated some items (in our example-dataset the variables "var1", "var2" and "var3").

I would like to get the intraclass variance for each group. In particular i would like to calculate the r*wg(j), ICC(1) and ICC(2).

I looked for a solution but the icc function in r expect to have the raters (my team members) as columns and not as row. I could find a way to do it by creating a subset for every group and then transposing every dataset but I believe there is an easier solution.

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this.

```
group <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)
var1 <- c(4, 5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 8, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5)
var2 <- c(2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 9, 3, 3, 2, 5, 4)
var3 <- c(4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 3, 6)
df <- data.frame(group, var1, var2, var3)
```

Comment: I didn't actually implemented it...it was just the only idea i had to solve the problem but it would be very "not elegant" and require a long code